# angular 2 getting plunker to work

Tags: angular, angular2-services, plunker

Hi I'm want to enter an angular 2 plunk and i'm stuck already by trying to provide a service...

I've added the TestSerivce inside the ngModule under

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  providers: [TestService]
})
```

and here the Service

```
@Injectable()

export class TestService{
  constructor(){
    console.log('Service')  
  }

}
```

It should be RC5 and its throwing the following error

> zone.js:323 Error: (SystemJS) ReferenceError: TestService is not
>   defined
>         at eval (http://run.plnkr.co/BSJ1Mhu8FJ6lsnSD/src/app.ts!transpiled:46:37)
>         at execute (http://run.plnkr.co/BSJ1Mhu8FJ6lsnSD/src/app.ts!transpiled:51:14)
>     Error loading http://run.plnkr.co/BSJ1Mhu8FJ6lsnSD/src/main.ts

[Here's the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MwRiXRXoc9fmEqcLDsf?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `app.ts` module, it should be **TestService**, not **TestSerivce**:

import { <strike>TestSerivce</strike> **TestService** } from './service.ts'